# Adding css style to window.print() without @media print

Tags: html, css, media-queries

`@media print` is having issues with IE. And my application has to run with IE.
I would like to know whether there is any way around to apply the style other than the known method with `@media` printer?

I have a huge list of styles to be applied when printing the page. The page to be printed is the current page loaded in tomcat web application.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of media queries you can use new file for print styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

It works fine in old browsers too.

Comment: when you specify media="print"
its for @media print which is not what I was asking.

Comment: I meant you don't want to use media queries, which don't work min older IEs. There is no other way how to set styles for print.

Comment: Whether it's in `@media print` or `media="print"`, `print` is still a media query (or more specifically a media query consisting of only a media type). That's the point. It should work in IE either way.